# When sitefinity project rebuild sometime some dll change then never build again

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, content-management-system, sitefinity

When sitefinity project rebuild sometime some dll change then never build again.

I am using sitefinity 6.3 version. When i rebuild sitefinity project some time some dll change(I don't know what actually happening), than it will not build again.

But when i clean project and then build, so there is no problem.

I know 99% is same as rebuild = Clean+Build.

So whats a problem while rebuild sitefinity project and what a changes occur while create new dll.

Comment: Essentially csproj files are msbuild scripts and can be customized. You could examine verbose build logs in order to find out the difference, if you have time for that. Otherwise, you could just make a cmd file `msbuild.exe SolutionName.sln /t:"Clean;Build"` as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have two or more projects in your solution.

What **Rebuild** does is, it will take project by project and **delete all compiled files for project1 + build project1 then delete all compiled files for project2 + build project2 and so on.**

From the other hand if you do **Clean + Build** what's done is  **all of your compiled files of all project will be deleted first, one by one and then the projects will be built** one after each other.

**The differences is the way build and clean sequence happen for every project.**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In the case for sitefinity, any toll or something should be integrate there to resolving problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the technical reasons why your can't use rebuild or clean & ruibuild, all I know is it causes the the dlls to go "missing". If this happens you'll need to replace the default dlls back into the project as they will not be restored. Make it a habit to only use build, never clean or rebuild